# Append external svg using d3 and Webpack in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js, svg, webpack

What I want to do is load in multiple external `svg` images using `import` with webpack, and append them to a group using d3. I'm currently using d3's `.html` method to do so, but it doesn't work in IE11 and below.

Here's how it's set up now:

```
import aerosolsImage from '../../images/topic-aerosols.svg'
import cloudsImage from '../../images/topic-clouds.svg'
import fireImage from '../../images/topic-fire.svg'

const topicsToImages = {
  'aerosols': aerosolsImage,
  'clouds': cloudsImage,
  'fire': fireImage
}

...

// called every few seconds to trigger new animation
function start (topic, animationLayer) {
  const g = animationLayer.append('g')
  ...
  g.append('g')
    .html(topicsToImages[topic]);
}
```

Loading the SVG with webpack returns a string like this:

```
"<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg>"
```

Is there another way to append the SVGs using d3 that works in IE? Open to ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future coders who have this same issue, I found a solution.

You can use this [innerSVG polyfill mirror](https://github.com/dnozay/innersvg-polyfill).

Install with npm:

```
npm install innersvg-polyfill --save-dev
```

import with webpack:

```
import * as innerSVG from 'innersvg-polyfill'
```

and voila, you can now use d3's `.html` or vanilla `.innerHTML` method with svg nodes cross-browser :)

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks so much for this + the import example! You're a true StackOverflow hero :)